# «По» со сложными наречиями

Tags: правописание, наречия

> В эту минуту рядом проходил какой-то знатный вельможа, — шляпа Тома
>   Ивза слетела с его головы, и он бросился вперед с поклоном и улыбкой.
>   Это доказывало, что и он тоже знает свет — по-своему, по том-ивзовски,
>   конечно.

*Уильям Мейкпис Теккерей. «Ярмарка тщеславия». Перевод М. Дьяконова.*

Как и почему должно правильно писаться «по том-ивзовски»?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*По-том-ивзовски*.

From Lopatin's *Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации*:

> § 138. Пишутся через дефис:
>
> …
>
> 2. Наречия с приставкой *по-*, оканчивающиеся на *-ому, -ему, -ски, -цки, -ьи* … *по-социал-демократически, по-жюль-верновски, по-тёти-Валиному*.

That's quite a recent innovation, 1956's rules called for a single hyphen here: *по-томивзовски*.

Comment: Bearing in mind “по-тёти-Валиному”, should I consider using «по-Том-Ивзовски»?

Comment: @VadimPushtaev: rules are inconclusive in that regard, but the spirit of it is that you should preserve the capital if the word on its own would have been written with a capital: *Валин сын* but *жюль-верновский капитан*. I have read an article not so long ago, criticizing that very inconsistency.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answer.We know that adverbs are formed from the adjectives. Let's consider how complex adjectives are formed. «Через дефис пишутся сложные прилагательные,образованные от сочетания имени и фамилии, имени и отчества, **разговорные по стилевой принадлежности**:

> вальтер-скоттовские романы – по-вальтер-скоттовски(наречие).робин-гудовские приключения – по-робин-гудовски.

В отдельных случаях встречается слитное написание :

> тарасобульбовская сила, веропавловские мастерские».

If we speak of belonging to individual people, (not about characters):

> Анна-Михайловнина кофта.(with capital letters).

The same rule is valid speaking about adverbs with *по-*. It should be written **по-том-ивзовски**, as stated at the very beginning.
 Это по Розенталю.

Прилагательные,обозначающие индивидуальную принадлежность, пишутся с **прописной** буквы, если они образованы от собственных имен при помощи суффикса **-ов-,-ев-,-ин-**.(Надина кукла,Одиссеевы странствия).Но подобные прилагательные пишутся со **строчной** буквы во фразеологических оборотах и научныз терминах (ахиллесова пята,базедова болезнь).

Прилагательные, обозначающие принадлежность, образованные от собственных имен лиц, пишутся со **строчной** буквы,если имеют суффикс **-ск-**(шекспировские трагедии).
Розенталь Прописная или строчная.

Comment: I don't believe it's reality of the person which defines capitalization. _Ньютонова жидкость_ and _декартово произведение_ are not capitalized. Here, the adjectives are in fact descriptive, not possessive: _ньютоновская жидкость_ and _декартовское произведение_ would have made as much if not more sense (it's Cartesian and Newtonian, not Descartes' and Newton's, after all). _Анна-Михайловнина_, on its turn, is a true possessive, and that's why it's capitalized.

Comment: I deserve an ice-cream, don't you think?(A joke, you can delete it).

Comment: we are supposed to be dead serious, square-glasses, plaid-clad, pencil-behind-the-ear people in our little belles lettres lovers club. No ice-cream for you.

Comment: Unicode has emoji for everything now. Ice Cream emoji:  and Soft Ice Cream emoji:  and Shaved Ice emoji: 